# Is there anyway to put regular expression on mysql column

Tags: mysql

I am beginner to MySQL, so my question is: when create a new column in a specific table, is there any way to write regular expression to detect accepted value before inserting?
the main Idea from question is to add domain name column and I need to check if user entry matching my requirements before accept the value to store in database.
I hope my question cleared.

note: I cant use PHP or any front end language, it's necessary to do that in mysql database
thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What database version? If not sure, the version usually appears after accessing the mysql prompt, or you can run query `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: If you're using 8.x you can use `CHECK` constraints. https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-16-introducing-check-constraint/

Comment: @PaulT. I' not sure now until our system administrator answer me. thank you

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot ,so check constraints can help me to use regular expression?

Comment: You can put any expression in the `CHECK` constraint, so you can use `colname RLIKE 'regex'`

Comment: @Barmar is this also can work with mariaDB 10.2.9?

Comment: Yes, it was added in 10.2.1.

Comment: @Barmar thanks I'm trying to use it but system accepted wrong word. I added constraint as: check (column_name rlike  '[A-Za-z0-9]{2,63}') but when try to insert value it's accept value likes: 'aaa.be' or 'a'  or 'rrr---d'. can you advice me please ?

Comment: You need to anchor the regexp with `^` and `$`, otherwise it will match anywhere in the string, not just the whole string.

Comment: @Barmar you saved my life. thank you friend